# Monotouch iPhone 5 build and app that supports ARM6

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, armv7

I'm wondering what I need to do with my existing application when I build it. Currently I target ARM6 and ARM7 using 4.0 as my target build SDK.

I don't really want to drop ARM6 support but I also want to make sure that my app can be used on the new iPhone. From what I can tell Apple also won't let you drop support for ARM6 on apps that are already in the store and support that architecture.

Do I have to create a new version of my application just for iPhone 5 users?

Comment: What's your source for "Apple also won't let you drop support for ARM6 on apps that are already in the store and support that architecture."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple lets you drop ARMv6 support.

The trick is that you have to set the Deployment Target to an iOS version that is guaranteed to have ARMv7 support (I believe this would be 4.3).

That said, you do not have to drop ARMv6 just to make your app run on iPhone 5, your existing app will work just fine (but you will not be able to use any of the new iOS 6 features).

Answer (score 0):

What if I don't want to drop the ARMv6 support? A lot of people are still using the old phones. My app just needs to support fullscreen on iPhone5.

This basically means that Apple has prevented the same app from running on iPhone 5 and older phones!

I'll try to submit the iPhone5 version as a separate app on iTunes connect, so that people can use the app on older phones and still enjoy full screen on iPhone 5. let's hope Apple doesn't reject my app - it's their fault after all!

Comment: That is the only way that you can do it. Unfortunately the older phone users won't be able to enjoy any new features that you create.